# Add streams dynamically to combined stream (eg forkJoin)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

My function (lets call it `myFunction`) is getting an array of streams (`myFunction(streams: Observable<number>[])`). Each of those streams produces values from 1 to 100, which acts as a progress indicator. When it hits 100 it is done and completed. Now, when all of those observables are done I want to emit a value. I could do it this way:

```js
public myFunction(streams: Observable<number>[]) {
  forkJoin(streams).subscribe(_values => this.done$.emit());
}
```

This works fine, but imagine following case:

1. myFunction gets called with 2 streams
2. one of those streams is done, second one is still progressing
3. myFunction gets called (again) with 3 more streams (2nd one from previous call is still progressing)

I'd like to somehow add those new streams from 3rd bullet to the "queue", which would result in having 5 streams in forkJoin (1 completed, 4 progressing).

I've tried multiple approaches but can't get it working anyhow... My latest approach was this:

```js
private currentProgressObs: Observable<any> | null = null;
private currentProgressSub: Subscription | null = null;

public myFunction(progressStreams: Observable<number>[]) {
    const isUploading = this.cumulativeUploadProgressSub && !this.cumulativeUploadProgressSub.closed;
    const currentConcatObs = this.currentProgressObs?.pipe(concatAll());
    const currentStream = isUploading && this.currentProgressObs ? this.currentProgressObs : of([100]);
        if (this.currentProgressSub) {
            this.currentProgressSub.unsubscribe();
            this.currentProgressSub = null;
        }
        this.currentProgressObs = forkJoin([currentStream, ...progressStreams]);
        this.currentProgressSub = this.currentProgressObs.subscribe(
            _lastProgresses => {
                this._isUploading$.next(false); // <----- this is the event I want to emit when all progress is completed
                this.currentProgressSub?.unsubscribe();
                this.currentProgressSub = null;
                this.currentProgressObs = null;
            },
        );
}
```

Above code only works for the first time. Second call to the `myFunction` will never emit the event.

I also tried other ways. I've tried recursion with one global stream array, in which I can add streams while the subscription is still avctive but... I failed. How can I achieve this? Which operator and in what oreder should I use? Why it will or won't work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion for your issue.

We will have two subjects, one to count the number of request being processed (`requestsInProgress`) and one more to mange the requests that are being processed (`requestMerger`)

So the thing that will do is whenever we want to add new request we will pass it to the `requestMerger` Subject.

Whenever we receive new request for processing in the `requestMerger` stream we will first increment the `requestInProgress` counter and after that we will merge the request itself in the source observable. While merging the new request/observable to the source we will also add the `finalize` operator in order to track when the request has been completed (reached 100), and when we hit the completion criteria we will decrement the request counter with the `decrementCounter` function.

In order to emit result e.g. to notify someone else in the app for the state of the pending requests we can subscribe to the `requestsInProgress` Subject.

You can test it out either here or in this [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-with-dinamic-n-of-requests?file=index.ts)

```js
let {
  interval,
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject 
} = rxjs
let {
  mergeMap,
  map,
  takeWhile,
  finalize,
  first,
  distinctUntilChanged
} = rxjs.operators


// Imagine next lines as a service
// Subject responsible for managing strems
let requestMerger = new Subject();
// Subject responsible for tracking streams in progress
let requestsInProgress = new BehaviorSubject(0);

function incrementCounter() {
  requestsInProgress.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => {
    requestsInProgress.next(x + 1);
  });
}

function decrementCounter() {
  requestsInProgress.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => {
    requestsInProgress.next(x - 1);
  });
}
// Adds request to the request being processed
function addRequest(req) {
  // The take while is used to complete the request when we have `value === 100` , if you are dealing with http-request `takeWhile` might be redudant, because http request complete by themseves (e.g. the finalize method of the stream will be called even without the `takeWhile` which will decrement the requestInProgress counter)
  requestMerger.next(req.pipe(takeWhile(x => x < 100)));
}
// By subscribing to this stream you can determine if all request are processed or if there are any still pending
requestsInProgress
  .pipe(
    map(x => (x === 0 ? "Loaded" : "Loading")),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
    document.getElementById("loadingState").innerHTML = x;
  });

// This Subject is taking care to store or request that are in progress
requestMerger
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(x => {
      // when new request is added (recieved from the requestMerger Subject) increment the requrest being processed counter
      incrementCounter();
      return x.pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          // when new request has been completed decrement the requrest being processed counter
          decrementCounter();
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
  });
// End of fictional service

// Button that adds request to be processed
document.getElementById("add-stream").addEventListener("click", () => {
  addRequest(interval(1000).pipe(map(x => x * 25)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:flex">
<button id="add-stream">Add stream</button>

<h5>Loading State:  <span id="loadingState">false</span> </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each time your call your function, you are creating a new observable.  Your life would be much easier if all calls of your function pushed all upload jobs through the same stream.

You can achieve this using a [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects).

I would suggest you push single "Upload Jobs" though a simple subject and design an observable that emits the state of all upload jobs whenever anything changes: A simple class that offers a `createJob()` method to submit jobs, and a `jobs$` observable to reference the state:

```js
class UploadService {
  private jobs = new Subject<UploadJob>();
  public jobs$ = this.jobs.pipe(
    mergeMap(job => this.processJob(job)),
    scan((collection, job) => collection.set(job.id, job), new Map<string, UploadJob>()),
    map(jobsMap => Array.from(jobsMap.values()))
  );

  constructor() {
    this.jobs$.subscribe();
  }

  public createJob(id: string) {
    this.jobs.next({ id, progress: 0 });
  }
  
  private processJob(job: UploadJob) {
    // do work and return observable that
    // emits updated status of UploadJob
  }
}
```

Let's break it down:

- `jobs` is a simple subject, that we can push "jobs" through
- `createJob` simply calls `jobs.next()` to push the new job through the stream
- `jobs$` is where all the magic happens.  It receives each `UploadJob` and uses:

  - [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to execute whatever function actually does the work (*I called it processJob() for this example*) and emits its values into the stream
  - [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) is used to accumulate these `UploadJob` emissions into a Map (*for ease of inserting or updating*)
  - `map` is used to convert the map into an array (`Map<string, UploadJob>` => `UploadJob[]`)
- `this.jobs$.subscribe()` is called in the constructor of the class so that jobs will be processed

---

Now, we can easily derive your `isUploading` and `cumulativeProgress` from this `jobs$` observable like so:

```
  public isUploading$ = this.jobs$.pipe(
    map(jobs => jobs.some(j => j.progress !== 100)),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  public progress$ = this.jobs$.pipe(
    map(jobs => {
      const current = jobs.reduce((sum, j) => sum + j.progress, 0) / 100;
      const total   = jobs.length ?? current;
      
      return current / total;
    })
  );
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67209856?file=index.ts) demo.